# Facebook Graph API: Permissions to Friends Photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm a bit confused. I have the proper permissions for my access token (friends_photos):

id is a friends id.
This:
`https://graph.facebook.com/id/albums?access_token=...` 
returns properly

But:

`https://graph.facebook.com/id/photos?access_token=...` 
returns empty.

Whats the proper request for all photos a friend is tagged in?

Comment: I doubt that. AFAIK `friends_photos` is not a valid permission anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

### **Facebook has removed this permission, it will not work any more.**

Friends photos permissions are = friends_photos

If you are not getting photos back then it could be due to permissions. A easy way to test that out is goto graph.facebook.com , check your own full access key by clicking one of the example links (i.e your friends). Use that key when trying to get a friends photos. If it works then they have disabled application access to their own photos.

The permission api info is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/